# How can $ \langle -1 \rangle $ be the same as C2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

How can $ \langle -1 \rangle $ be the same as $ \text{C2} =\{-1, 1\} $?

Why can we just write $ \langle -1 \rangle $?
Why do we say that $ \{-1, 1 \} $ is generated by $ \langle -1 \rangle $?
With $ \langle -1 \rangle $ we get $ \{ \ldots, -3, -2, -1 \} $, and with $ \langle -1 \rangle $ we get $ \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \} $.
I am really confused.

Comment: Even if the group's operation *was* addition, then $\langle -1 \rangle = \Bbb Z = \langle 1 \rangle$, as subgroups of $\Bbb Z$: We get to use inverses of generators in addition to the generators themselves.

Answer (score 4):

The operation here is multiplication, so $\langle -1 \rangle$ is generated by powers of $-1$, which are $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: I don't think this addresses OP's confusion. It is really about mixing up additive and multiplicative, more than that $ \langle -1 \rangle = \{ -1, 1 \} $.

Answer (score 0):

> How can $\langle -1 \rangle$ be the same as $\text{C2} = \{ 1, -1 \} $?

$ \langle g \rangle $ is defined as the group "generated" by some element $ g $. In particular, we say that a group, $ G $, is generated by $ g $, if $ \langle g \rangle = \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} : g^n \} = G$.

Now, we take $ -1 \in Z^\times$. Now, $ \{ n \in \mathbb{Z} : {(-1)}^n \} = \{ 1, -1 \} $.

> Why can we just write $\langle -1 \rangle$ ?

Because they are the equal.

> Why do we say that $ \{ -1, 1 \} $ is generated by $ \langle -1 \rangle $?

Well, it is "generated" in the sense, that you can take the set $ \{ -1 \} $ and "extend" it under multiplication and inverses, and you get $ \{ -1, 1 \} $.

Intuitively, $ \langle g \rangle $ can be thought of as the smallest group, with $ g \in G $.

> With $ \langle -1 \rangle $ we get $ \{ \ldots, -3, -2, -1 \} $, and with $ \langle -1 \rangle $ we get $ \{1, 2, 3, \ldots \} $.

The confusion is here that $ \langle -1 \rangle $ is really ambiguous, and requires context to be understood. If you consider $ \mathbb{Z} $ under addition, you generate it from *adding* $ -1 $, and thus you get $ \mathbb{Z} $. If you consider $ \mathbb{Z} $ under multiplication ($ \mathbb{Z}^\times $), the story is different.